# String comparision difference in different ways in java

Tags: java, string, comparison, hashmap, string-comparison

I have two strings and i think i mean according to my eyes they are exactly same. But their comparision gives me wrong result.

let me explain briefly,

```
String bir = "brescia calcio";
String iki = "brescia calcio‎";
 if("brescia calcio".equals("brescia calcio"))
 System.out.println(("deneme"));



HashMap<String, Long> deneme = new HashMap<String, Long>();
HashMap<String, Long> deneme2 = new HashMap<String, Long>();


if (bir.equals(iki)) {
    System.err.println("a");
}
deneme.put(bir, (long) 1);
deneme.put(iki, (long) 2);

deneme2.put("brescia calcio", (long) 3);
deneme2.put("brescia calcio", (long) 4);



System.err.println(deneme.size());
System.err.println(deneme2.size());
```

the piece of code above produces

deneme
2
1

output. i m totally confused about it. can someone please explain why is it so. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a non-printable character at the end which you can't see.

```
String iki = "brescia calcio‎";

for(int i=0;i<iki.length();i++)
    System.out.println(i+": "+iki.charAt(i)+" (" + (int) iki.charAt(i)+")");
```

prints

```
0: b (98)
1: r (114)
2: e (101)
3: s (115)
4: c (99)
5: i (105)
6: a (97)
7:   (32)
8: c (99)
9: a (97)
10: l (108)
11: c (99)
12: i (105)
13: o (111)
14: ‎ (8206)
```

Answer (score 11):

In your second string, `iki`, you have a nonprintable character right at the end. When I copy and paste that string into `vim`, I see

```
String iki = "brescia calcio‎<200e>";
```

I bet the mystery will be solved once you remove that character.

In case you're wondering, [U+200E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) is the [left-to-right mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark).

Comment: Beat me to it. :-) And yes, if you remove the char you get the result expected.

Comment: How the hell did you manage to see that?! My compliments, good response! :)

Comment: nice catch! i suspected also that there was a special character since i could not save after i copy pasted it into eclipse. I got a message like "Some characters cannot be mapped using Cp1252 character encoding."